# How to guarantee that one subscriber is only ever called once, but before all other subscribers?

Tags: redux, rxjs

I have a redux state with RxJS listeners, where the state is an Observable that looks something like:

```js
type State = {
  organizations: Array<Organization>;
  licenses: Array<License>
  user: User;
}
```

I have a set of observables observing some specific part of the state, and another set of observers subscribed to each of those observables.

```js
(state: Observable<State>) => {
  // Observerables
  const didChangeOrganizations: Observable<Array<Organization>> = state.pipe(
    map(({ organization }) => organization),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  const didChangeUser: Observable<User> = state.pipe(
    map(({ user }) => user),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  const didChangeLicenses: Observable<Array<License>> = state.pipe(
    map(({ licenses }) => licenses),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  const userId = Observable<string> = state.pipe(
    map(({ user }) => user.id),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  // Observers
  didChangeUser.subscribe(user => {
    const traits = {...};
    analytics.identify(user.id, traits);
  });

  combineLatest(userId, didChangeLicenses).subscribe(([userId, licenses]) => {
    analytics.identify(userId, { licenses });
  });

  ...

  combineLatest(userId, didChangeOrganizations).subscribe(
    ([userId, organizations]) => {
      // if no orgs exist yet, we know this is the first time the user 
      // logged in, which in this case we should call alias
      if (organizations.length === 0) {
        analytics.alias(userId);
      }

      ...
      analytics.identify(userId, { org: ..., orgUrl: ... })
    }
  );
}
```

The problem I'm facing is I must call `analytics.alias` only ever one time (the time the user first logs in), but it must be before `analytics.identify` is ever called.

Each subscriber independently calls `identify` watching its own state change, which may happen at any time.

How can I construct the observables or observers to handle this dependency, where I can essentially "hold off" on calling any `identify`'s UNTIL `alias` is called ONLY IF its the user's first log-in?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this:

```js
const firstTimeUser$ = combineLatest(userId, didChangeOrganizations).pipe(share());

// Following the same pattern for each observer that has `analytics.identify`
didChangeUser
  .pipe(skipUntil(firstTimeUser$.pipe(delay(0))))
  .subscribe(user => {
    const traits = {...};
    analytics.identify(user.id, traits);
  });

combineLatest(userId, didChangeLicenses)
  .pipe(skipUntil(firstTimeUser$.pipe(delay(0))))
  .subscribe(([userId, licenses]) => {
  analytics.identify(userId, { licenses });
});

firstTimeUser$.subscribe(() => /* ... */)
```

We're using `share()` because `firstTimeUser$` is subscribed in three 3 places and we wouldn't want to invoke the source 3 times. What `share()` does it to place a `Subject` between the data producer(e.g: `combineLatest(userId, didChangeOrganizations)`) and the data consumers(e.g `.subscribe()`, `skipUntil`'s inner subscriber).

So, run our program will start listening to events, that `Subject` mentioned above will have 3 subscribers:

```js
[
  InnerSubscriber, // First `skipUntil`
  InnerSubscriber, // Second `skipUntil`
  Subscriber // From `firstTimeUser$.subscribe`
]
```

We're adding `delay(0)` because we want `Subscriber` to be the first subscriber that receives the values, which is where `alias` will be called for the first and time.

And because we're using `skipUntil(notifier)`, it will skip values until `notifier` emits once.

Comment: instead of `skipUntil`, does some sort of `waitUntil` operator exist in rxjs? ideally id like for it to still eventually call rather than skip. the only way i've gotten around this so far is to actually include firstTimeUser$ in a combineLatest with didChangeUser$ and didChangeLicenses$ before subscribing

Comment: If you don't want to skip it, but just wait for it, you can replace `skipUntil(...)` with: `switchMap((v, idx) => idx === 0 ? firstTimeUser$.pipe(delay(0)).pipe(mapTo(v), take(1)) : of(v))`. With `idx === 0` we can wait until `alias` is called only once(the first time)